# How to prevent darkening of wrist?

Tags: wrist

I have noticed that when I use computer for long hours, a part of my wrist and palm color turns dark brownish because of the excessive use of the mouse. And this darkening of skin doesn't go away by washing my hands.

[image]

In the above picture I have encircled the part of my hand which gets darkened. Is there anything I can do to prevent this? It is not possible for me to use computer less.

Comment: what surface do you use your mouse on? this sounds like staining from paint or dye that is rubbing off on your skin. maybe try putting down  a wrist rest, or other pad or a small towel folded up. or you could try using nail polish remover on your skin to see if that shifts it (NOTE - be sensible here, it may irritate)

Comment: It sounds like there's only 2 things you can do. 1. Change the surface you're coming in contact with by getting a new mouse mat or the like. 2. Isolate yourself from that surface, perhaps wearing a wristband.

Comment: @jammypeach - I use mouse pad and my hand mostly rests on the edge of the table of computer. Yes, I should give nail polish remover a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: Wearing a wrist band sounds very convincing. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question as it seems to fall under personal medical advice, but if you're seriously concerned, it would be best to check with a doctor.

Comment: I actually went to the doctor about this thinking the worst about it considering skin darkens wioth skin cancer, too. But the doctor was pressing down on the dark spot and had a tool to enhance his hearing and he showed me that when he presses down on it it makes sort of a rubbing noise but its fluid in the tendon there that builds up because of excessive pressure. its completely harmless, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a cordless keyboard and get used to using the mouse pad and keyboard shortcuts as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Its pressure that's causing the problem - on my hand, that area is darkened, constantly reddish purple; on a friend who uses the computer for up to 18 hours a day, he's got a purplish, reddish brown, calloused, dry area in that region. When you use the mouse, unless you've got a special mat which raises your wrist, that area rests on the desk or work surface. It's a bony area, without much padding over it, so your body's trying to compensate for the constant pressure, the way it does on our feet by building hard skin and callouses. You either need to pad that area of your wrist with something, or get a mouse mat which has a support bar to stop this problem. I find the support mats very uncomfortable to use, but lots of people do have them.

Comment: A support bar will lead to other problems though: without the support bar, you can use your entire arm to move the mouse. With the support bar, you only use your wrist, leading to wrist problems. The pad also puts pressure on the wrist, compressing the carpal tunnel which also causes wrist trouble.

Comment: Yea, I hate the things personally, I just put up with the discoloration... but actually, I still only use my wrist/hand, don't move my arm around at all...

Comment: @Bamboo - I have seen people getting permanent discoloration. I am just afraid of that.

Comment: @Hobbes: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Place the mouse close enough to the edge of your work surface that your hand does not touch the surface.

2) Use a trackball.